# Error when splitting a string

Tags: java, split

Im having this really weird issue that i haven't been able to figure out for a few hours. Basically im trying to split this `getInterfaceBounds-client.ry`, what im doing is this

```
final String className = line.split(".")[0];
```

im getting a `arrayindexoutofbounds` exception. I really have no idea why, do you?

`Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: Check the size of the array you get when you do line.split(".")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` uses a regular expression.  In regex `.` means any character, so you need to escape it.

Try:

```
final String className = line.split("\\.")[0];
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 1):

The change required is :

```
final String className = line.split("\\.")[0];
```

Check this example for more details.

```
  String s="getInterfaceBounds-client.ry";
  String[] arr = s.split("\\.");
  for(String str : arr)
  {
    System.out.println(str);
  }
```

Ideone [link](http://ideone.com/39XzRn).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead and it will work. I just tested it.

```
String line = "getInterfaceBounds-client.ry";

String className = line.split("[.]")[0]; 

System.out.println(className);
```

The . is a special character in regex which represent any character.

You can learn more about the different special characters in regex here:
http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Array variable for `split()` beacuse we may get more than  a value from splitting  so it would be helpful if u use array it would avoid confusion of accesing the values for example:

```
String line = "getInterfaceBounds-client.ry.test";
String test[] = line.split("[.]");
System.out.println(test[0]+test[1]+test[2]);
```